# Access php file via AJAX returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

Created a plugin that should access this file via AJAX:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/stemon-mailchimp-form/assets/sm_mailchimp.php
```

However it is returning 403 Forbidden.

Tried adding this to `.htaccess` but no success yet.

```
<Files ~ "\wp-content\plugins\stemon-mailchimp-form\.php$">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to figure why the 403 was occuring in the first place, before trying to _workaround_ this issue (as you appear to be doing). (Incidentally, the `<Files>` directive matches filenames only, not file paths.)

Comment: Thanks MrWhite, how you'd suggest I'd figure out why the 403 is happening? Thanks

Comment: And, suppose I need to write the allow rule in `.htaccess`, should I `<Files ~ "sm_mailchimp.php">` like this?

Comment: "figure out why the 403" - Maybe it's caused by other directives in `.htaccess`? Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question.

Comment: I cleaned it all and still not working, only left the `# BEGIN Wordpress` part. Does that mean the issue is not on `.htaccess`? If not, where would it be? Could Cloudflare have something to do with it?

Comment: Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories along the filesystem path? Do you have any other files in this subdirectory (if not, make one) ? Is it accessible?

Comment: Spot on. Created a `.htaccess` in the plugin directory and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help. Had lost hopes on this already :)

Comment: If you want to create an official answer, I will check it as valid

Comment: Glad this helped resolve the issue - that was initially intended to try and debug the issue - but that is one way to solve it! I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `.htaccess` file in the plugin subdirectory with specific directives from mod_auth... to *allow* access to this file should override any blocking directives in a parent `.htaccess` file further up the directory tree.

For example:

```
<Files "sm_mailchimp.php">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Files>
```

Note that the `Order` and `Allow` directives are Apache 2.2 directives (they still work on Apache 2.4 but are *deprecated*). If you are on Apache 2.4 then should really be using `Require all granted` instead of the above two directives.

The `<Files>` container matches against the filename only. No file-path should be specified here. Note also that this is not a regex match (although certain wildcards are permitted). It is the `~` in `<Files ~ "filename">` that makes it a regex match.

Note that if this is working then it is *overriding* a blocking directive elsewhere (probably in a `.htaccess` file in a parent directory). It maybe possible to override this in the same place, without creating another `.htaccess` file.